# Using regex to create a list of dictionaries with positive lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, positive-lookbehind

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries using regex positive lookbehind. I tried two different codes:

**Variation 1**

```
string = '146.204.224.152 - lubo233'

for item in re.finditer( "(?P<host>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)(?P<user_name>(?<= - )[a-z]*[0-9]*)", string ):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

**Variation 2**

```
string = '146.204.224.152 - lubo233'
for item in re.finditer( "(?P<host>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)(?<= - )(?P<user_name>[a-z]*[0-9]*)", string ):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

**Desired Output**

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'lubo233'}
```

**Question/Issue**

In both cases, I am unable to eliminate the substring " - ".

The use of positive lookbehind `(?<= - )` renders my code wrong.

Can anyone assist to identify my mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you remove the positive lookbehind and just put the join character normally, between each parts

Also some improvements

- `\.` instead of `[.]`
- `[0-9]{,3}` instead of `[0-9]*`
- `(?:\.[0-9]{,3}){3}` instead of `\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}`

Add a `.*` along with the `-` to handle any word that could be there

```
rgx = re.compile(r"(?P<host>[0-9]{,3}(?:\.[0-9]{,3}){3}).* - (?P<user_name>[a-z]*[0-9]*)")

vals = ['146.204.224.152 aw0123 abc - lubo233',
        '146.204.224.152 as003443af - lubo233',
        '146.204.224.152 - lubo233']

for val in vals:
    for item in rgx.finditer(val):
        print(item.groupdict())

# Gives
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'lubo233'}
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'lubo233'}
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'lubo233'}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. But what happens when there is an unknown length of characters between the two substrings: '146.204.224.152' and ' - lubo233'? Example: string = '146.204.224.152  aw0123 abc - lubo233' or string = '146.204.224.152 as003443af - lubo233'

Comment: @KaneChew Please edit your initial post to add several examples of input string. Also my code does the same as yours and its working, your initial code did NOT handle a possible different content in the middle ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the positive lookbehind is not working is that you are trying to match:

- `(?P<host>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)` an *IP address*
- **immediately** followed by a *user name pattern*: `(?P<user_name>(?<= - )[a-z]*[0-9]*)` that should be preceded by `(?<= - )`

So once the regex engine has consumed the *IP address* pattern you are telling that should match a *user name pattern* preceded by `(?<= - )` but what is preceding is the *IP address* pattern. In other terms, once the *IP pattern* has been matched the string left is:

```
- lubo233
```

The pattern that should be immediately matched, as in [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match), is:

```
(?P<user_name>(?<= - )[a-z]*[0-9]*)
```

that obviously does not match. To illustrate my point, see that this pattern works:

```
import re

string = '146.204.224.152 - lubo233'
for item in re.finditer(r"((?P<host>[0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)( - ))(?P<user_name>(?<= - )[a-z]*[0-9]*)", string):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

**Output**

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'lubo233'}
```

If you need to match an arbitrary number of characters between the two patterns, you could do:

```
import re

string = '146.204.224.152 adfadfa - lubo233'
for item in re.finditer(r"((?P<host>\d{3,}[.]\d{3,}[.]\d{3,})(.* - ))(?P<user_name>(?<= - )[a-z]*[0-9]*)", string):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

**Output**

```
{'host': '146.204.224', 'user_name': 'lubo233'}
```

Comment: Following your train of thought, "once the regex engine has consumed the IP address pattern",  the following substring is left: " - lubo233". In this case, isn't " - " preceding the user_name? Or am I not understanding regex properly?

Comment: @KaneChew positive lookbehind does not consume the string. As you said the string left is " - lubo233" and you are telling it, that it should be preceded by " - ".